# jquery is not working with this id #tel / fax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this id(tel / fax) in this line

```
$("#" + val.target.id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

then I get an error like:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #tel / fax

Comment: Is the attribute actually `id="tel / fax"`? If so that's not a valid value - you cannot have spaces in `id` attributes. Please add the HTML of the element you're trying to select to make the issue more clear.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: invalid id used here. only `_` or `-` will be used

Comment: yes <input id="tel / fax"... but i create a dynamic select with array value my array is ["id", "name", "location", "email", "gender", "tel / fax", "language preference", "credit card type"] . so create dynamic select box with id all field are working properly but this three field is not working "tel / fax", "language preference", "credit card type"

Comment: You can't have spaces in your `id`.

Comment: so your final selector is for elements looking like this: `<div id="language preference">` and `<div id="tel / fax">`. This does not work. You can't have spaces and slashes in ID

Comment: try `language-preference` and `tel-or-fax` and it will work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have spaces in id attribute. you can replace the space with any other character with replace() function.

Answer (score 0):

ID should be one word without spaces and special chars. jQuery selecting works same as css selecting. For example, if you cannot write in your css `#tel / fax {...}` then you cannot do same in your jQuery - `$('#tel / fax');` would throw you an error.

Just change your ID of element and it will work.